# Eclipse OSGI Import-Package issue after upgrading

Tags: osgi, eclipse-rcp, osgi-bundle

I am working on upgrading an Eclipse RCP Plugin. Many of our imported plugins (such as `org.eclipse.ui.workbench` and `org.eclipse.jface.text` have `"Import-Package: com.ibm.icu.text"` or `"Import-Package: com.ibm.icu.util"`.

For various reasons, we can only upgrade our Eclipse version to 4.16, however, we tried to upgrade the `com.ibm.icu` plugin for security reasons. I upgraded it through Orbit from version 64.2 to 67.1 because that is the oldest version that has the security fix.

However, once I upgraded it, my plugin no longer builds. I get the following error:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.ant.ui [32]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="[3.2.0,4.0.0)"; resolution:="optional"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.ide; bundle-version="3.17.100.v20200530-0835"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.ui.ide [238]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="[3.106.0,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui; bundle-version="3.117.0.v20200518-1705"; singleton:="true"
              org.eclipse.ui [230]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.119.0,4.0.0)"; visibility:="reexport"
                  -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.119.0.v20200521-1247"; singleton:="true"
                     org.eclipse.ui.workbench [253]
                       Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: com.ibm.icu.util
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="[3.115.100,4.0.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.ui.workbench; bundle-version="3.119.0.v20200521-1247"; singleton:="true"
```

The 2 packages that it seems to be missing are `com.ibm.icu.text` and `com.ibm.icu.util`. The manifest of the new version shows that it is still exporting those packages. I have no idea why it's no longer finding the packages. I have been trying to figure this out for days, and have had zero luck. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe com.ibm.icu has some Require-Capability that are not met? You could try to start the bundle com.ibm.icu via the console to see if there are any errors